# Should I make these rectangular PCB cutouts larger to account for corner radius?

Tags: pcb, connector

I am designing a PCB to fit one of [these SCART connectors](https://console5.com/store/female-scart-jp21-through-hole-pcb-mount-21-pin-connector-right-angle.html). The recommended PCB layout for the connector includes two rectangular cutouts, each 3.0 x 4.5 mm - these are designed to accommodate brackets that are 2.5 x 3.0 mm at their largest.

If I submit a board design with these cutouts to [OSH Park](https://oshpark.com/), they won't be fabricated as perfect rectangles. Instead [a 1.7272 mm mill end will be used](https://docs.oshpark.com/submitting-orders/board-outline/), so the rectangles will have a corner radius of 0.8636 mm.

Do I need to make the cutouts larger to allow for this corner radius?

The specified cutout length of 4.5 mm for a 3.0 mm bracket already includes 1.5 mm excess. Is this specifically to allow for a non-zero corner radius? Or is there another reason for it - in which case do I need to make the cutout even longer (adding twice the corner radius for a total length of 6.2272 mm)?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like it should be okay to me. The plastic will have a bit of a radius. If you want to be extra safe make the cutouts 5mm rather than 4.5.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So the 1.5 mm excess exists to allow for smooth corners, rather than to tolerate variance in the size/position of the brackets? Is that normal on this type of diagram?

Comment: I don’t know why they did it, possibly to allow some tolerance in movement as well. But plastic is soft and will deform, but not compress, so if there is room it should work. Increasing the 3mm dimension would likely cause the snap to not work.